# How can I print numbers in my assembly program

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

I have a problem with my assembly program. My assembly compiler is NASM. The source and the outputs are in this picture:

[image]

The problem is that I can't print numbers from calculations with the `extern C` function `printf()`. How can I do it?

The output should be "Ergebnis: 8" but it isn't correct.

Comment: What about your program makes you think it should print an 8?

Comment: val_1 and val_2 are both 4. I mov(e) val_1 in eax and add val_2 to eax then I pushed it to the stack with result string. It is like this in C:: int a = 4; int b = 4; printf("Ergebnis: %i", a + b);

Comment: What happens if you push an 8 explicitly instead of `eax`?  Have you verified that `eax` contains 8 when pushed?

Comment: `mov eax, val_1` does not do, what you think it does. Check the disassembly in debugger. NASM does use proper Intel syntax, so if you want value from memory, you have to specify that by using `[]` square brackets. And `val_1:` is not "name of variable", but "pointer into memory with address of first byte". Plus use colons after label names, even in `.data` definitions, it may save you from other obscure compilation problems (when you will hit instruction mnemonics by accident).

Comment: If I push 8 explicitly it works. No I don't verified this

Comment: Thanks it works with [] :D

Comment: How did you compile the code in this image? My compiler only gives errors.

Comment: nasm -f win32 add.asm; gcc -m32 -o add.exe add.obj

Comment: Thanks for help and all tipps :)

Comment: I don't know about you, but my assembler doesn't accept .png files as source input. Perhaps you should have posted the code as *plain text*?

Comment: Ahh, I uploaded a picture and you want to have text :D

Answer (score 4):

In [NASM documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html) it is pointed that *NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References*. When you write label name without bracket `NASM` gives its memory address (or offset as it is called sometimes). So, `mov eax, val_1` it means that `eax` register gets `val_1`'s offset. When you `add eax, val_2`, `val_2` offset is added to `val_1` offset and you get the result you see.

Write instead:

```
mov eax, [val_1]
add eax, [val_2]
```

And you shoul get `8` in eax.

P.S. It seems that you have just switched to `NASM` from `MASM` or `TASM`.
There are a lot of guides for switchers like you. See for example nice tutorials [here](http://rs1.szif.hu/~tomcat/win32/intro.txt) and [here](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/mp/f99/mp5/masm_nasm.html).

Comment: You seem to know what was wrong with the OP's program, yet you just re-write the same errors! Why don't you write `mov eax, [val_1]` `add eax, [val_2]` ?